# Spring Cloud Data Flow Task execution monitoring

Tags: spring-cloud-task

We have been looking into spring cloud task. It looks very promising but we seem to be missing how monitoring should work, especially for tasks that are executed from a stream.
For tasks manually executed from the dashboard there is an execution tab, but does not seem to be a page where you can find an overview of the tasks executed from within a stream.

What is the way to monitor the executions, exit codes, progress and other things for such tasks?

Answer (score 1):

The tasks that are executed from your stream will create a TaskExecution entry in the Task_Execution table just like tasks that executed from the dashboard.  In that case the executions tab will fill this need.